# Recursive Action Call in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, refresh-token, redux-promise

I have a scenario for implementing refresh auth token. In this scenario, I've implemented a general action for each kind of actions (Post,Get, Delete) and call them with parameters.

```
export function Get(param) {
return function (dispatch) {
    var query = param ? !!param.Query ? param.Query : "" : "";
    var funtionName = param ? param.FunctionName : "";
    var url = endPointUrl + funtionName;
    var offset = param.Offset ? param.Offset : "0";
    var limit = param.Limit ? param.Limit : "10";
    const config = { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('access-token') } };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(url, config).then((response) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCEED_' + param.Caller, payload: response.data })
            resolve(response.data);
        }).catch((error) => {
                if (error.request.status == "401" && error.request.statusText == "RB.Exception.TokenExpiredException") {
                    refreshToken().then(() => {
                        dispatch(Get(param));
                    });
                }
            else {
                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ERROR_' + param.Caller, payload: error })
                reject(error);
            }

        })
    })
}
```

whenever I receive TokenExpiredException, I call refreshToken() and then call the current action again (recursively), **so I can't use "then" in my component**.
do you have any solution about using "promise" or "then"?
I need to render some messages in component after action finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
export function Get(param) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        var query = param ? !!param.Query ? param.Query : "" : "";
        var funtionName = param ? param.FunctionName : "";
        var url = endPointUrl + funtionName;
        var offset = param.Offset ? param.Offset : "0";
        var limit = param.Limit ? param.Limit : "10";
        const config = { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('access-token') } };
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get(url, config).then((response) => {
                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCEED_' + param.Caller, payload: response.data })
                resolve(response.data);
            }).catch((error) => {
                if (error.request.status == "401" && error.request.statusText == "RB.Exception.TokenExpiredException") {
                    resolve(withRefresh(dispatch, param));
                }
                else {
                    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ERROR_' + param.Caller, payload: error })
                    reject(error);
                }

            })
        })
    }
}

function withRefresh(dispatch, param) {
    return refreshToken().then(() => {
        return dispatch(Get(param));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return your second promises which is `return dispatch(Get(param));`
Please try following code

```js
export function Get(param) {
return function (dispatch) {
    var query = param ? !!param.Query ? param.Query : "" : "";
    var funtionName = param ? param.FunctionName : "";
    var url = endPointUrl + funtionName;
    var offset = param.Offset ? param.Offset : "0";
    var limit = param.Limit ? param.Limit : "10";
    const config = { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('access-token') } };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(url, config).then((response) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCEED_' + param.Caller, payload: response.data })
            resolve(response.data);
        }).catch((error) => {
                if (error.request.status == "401" && error.request.statusText == "RB.Exception.TokenExpiredException") {
                    refreshToken().then(() => {
                        return dispatch(Get(param));
                    });
                }
            else {
                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ERROR_' + param.Caller, payload: error })
                reject(error);
            }

        })
    })
}
```

Comment: thank you, I tried your solution but it didn't work, as Hinrich said, we have to call "resolve"